# wget in Python unable to download the file I want

Tags: php, python, wget

I'm working on a small Python script that downloads some files from my university's website by using wget. The files I'm interested in are stored sequentially, where the link to the first file is: 
http://vlibcm.mmu.edu.my//xzamp/gxzam.php?action=37158.pdf

and then the links to the other files as follows:

http://vlibcm.mmu.edu.my//xzamp/gxzam.php?action=37159.pdf

http://vlibcm.mmu.edu.my//xzamp/gxzam.php?action=37160.pdf

and so the file numbers increase by an increment of 1 each time.

Here is the Python script I've written for it:

```
import wget, os, sys

BaseURL = "http://vlibcm.mmu.edu.my//xzamp/gxzam.php?action="
BaseNumber= 37158
FullURL = ''

DownloadLocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for i in range (3):
    FullURL = BaseURL + str(BaseNumber + i) + '.pdf'
    print ("Working on:", FullURL)
    wget.download(FullURL, DownloadLocation)
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
Downloading currently: http://vlibcm.mmu.edu.my//xzamp/gxzam.php?action=37158.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>    wget.download(FullURL, DownloadLocation)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download 
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve  
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error        
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain  
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MainUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 745, in http_error_302
    self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

There are two points that I'd like to note:

1. I am able to download this with IDM or my browser just fine
2. To download files from the university's website a VPN connection has to be made. I am connected to the university's VPN.

Comment: I don't know what IDM is, but could you try `wget` from the commandline? I'm not sure it's available for MS Windows, though. Another thing to watch out for is the influence of the user agent which the HTTP client (Why not HTTPS, btw?) reports. The server could check this string and decide to misbehave because it doesn't know wget.

Answer (score 0):

Error in urllib shows HTTP error 302. Read more about HTTP error 302 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302.

You may debug on browser first to make sure the file is available on the server.